# React-js how to trigger 'BeforeInstallPromptEvent' for launch the "pop up" add to homescreen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, prompt

I'm currently working on a react based app and I'm facing the PWA topic. I want to trigger and show when I want the pop-up that allows you to add the PWA to the home screen. I recently read that I can trigger it using BeforeInstallPromptEvent but there are some rules to follow like:
- The web app is not already installed
- Meets a user engagement heuristic (currently, the user has interacted with the domain for at least 30 seconds)
- Served over HTTPS (required for service workers)
- Has registered a service worker with a fetch event handler

Now I've all of those prerequisites but I actually unable to launch BeforeInstallPromptEvent, so I never viewed the pop-up, can someone help me?

Down you can find in which way I've intercepted this event

Thanks in advice

```py
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', function (e) {
    // Prevent Chrome 67 and earlier from automatically showing the prompt
    e.preventDefault()
    // Stash the event so it can be triggered later.
    deferredPrompt = e

    showAddToHomeScreen()
})

function showAddToHomeScreen() {

    var a2hsBtn = document.querySelector(".ad2hs-prompt");

    // @ts-ignore
    a2hsBtn.style.display = "block";

    // @ts-ignore
    a2hsBtn.addEventListener("click", addToHomeScreen);

}

function addToHomeScreen() {  var a2hsBtn = document.querySelector(".ad2hs-prompt");  // hide our user interface that shows our A2HS button
    // @ts-ignore
    a2hsBtn.style.display = 'none';  // Show the prompt
    deferredPrompt.prompt();  // Wait for the user to respond to the prompt
    deferredPrompt.userChoice
    // @ts-ignore
        .then(function(choiceResult){

            if (choiceResult.outcome === 'accepted') {
                console.log('User accepted the A2HS prompt');
            } else {
                console.log('User dismissed the A2HS prompt');
            }

            deferredPrompt = null;

        });}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi) Have you checked the platform/browser compatibility for the event?
[image: compatibility]

you can find it at the bottom of this page:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BeforeInstallPromptEvent

it's triggered only in Chrome on my device (Android). It does not work on the iPhone.

The event is triggered when the browser is ready to show the default PWA prompt or you can show the customized prompt.
I believe it's the compatibility issue.

Hope, it will help you